# JWT Token authorization in Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

Spring Boot version: 3.1.2

So, I'm using Spring Boot Webflux and R2DBC. I want to implement JWT Token authorization. I wrote several classes, but the main ones are:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthFilter authFilter;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomerUsersService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/welcome/**")
                .authenticated().and()
                .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager())
                .addFilterAt(authFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService());
        authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

JwtAuthFilter.java:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        System.out.println(("Incoming request: {}" + exchange.getRequest().getURI()));

        return Mono.justOrEmpty(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization"))
                .filter(authHeader -> authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
                .map(authHeader -> authHeader.substring(7))
                .flatMap(token -> {

                    System.out.println(("Extracted token: {}" + token));

                    return jwtService.extractUsername(token)
                            .flatMap(username -> {

                                System.out.println(("Extracted username: {}" + username));

                                if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

                                    String table = jwtService.extractClaim(token, claims -> claims.get("table", String.class));

                                    System.out.println("Table: " + table);

                                    return loadUserDetails(username, table)
                                            .flatMap(userDetails -> {

                                                System.out.println(("Loaded user details: {}" + userDetails.getUsername()));

                                                return jwtService.validateToken(token, userDetails)
                                                        .flatMap(isValid -> {

                                                            System.out.println(("Token is valid: {}" + isValid));

                                                            if (isValid) {

                                                                jwtService.extractUsername(token)
                                                                        .subscribe(username1 -> {
                                                                            MyIdentity = username1;
                                                                            System.out.println(MyIdentity);
                                                                        });

                                                                Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                                                                SecurityContextImpl securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl(authentication);
                                                                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

                                                                // Log the security context after it has been set
                                                                System.out.println("Security context set: " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
                                                            }

                                                            System.out.println(("SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(): {} " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()));

                                                            return chain.filter(exchange);
                                                        });
                                            });
                                } else {
                                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                                }
                            });
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange));
    }
// rest of the code
```

Lastly, My Welcome Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class Welcome {

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_OWNER')")
    public Mono<String> signUp() {


        return Mono.just("You are not logged in");
    }
}
```

When i log in and successfully authenticate, i get jwt token, that i insert in Bearer Token in postman to access /welcome endpoint, but it doesn't authenticate.

Logs that i get:

```
Incoming request: {}http://localhost:5555/login
Gulnoza Gulnoza Owner
Owner is being checked
Authorities: {} [ROLE_OWNER]
Gulnoza Gulnoza
Owner is being checked API
Owner is being checked
Owner is being checked
Authorities: {} [ROLE_OWNER]
Role: [ROLE_OWNER]
Authorities: {} [ROLE_OWNER]
Incoming request: {}http://localhost:5555/welcome
Extracted token: {}eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0YWJsZSI6Im93bmVycyIsInN1YiI6Ikd1bG5vemEiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTE1NzAwMTgsImV4cCI6MTY5MTc4NjAxOH0.g0zJb-PoNGxJZTcS6RbTsdhk_h_Aw_njYuBFNdhZTMY
Extracted username: {}Gulnoza
Table: owners
LoadUserDetails Owners Is Being Checked Using Table: owners
Authorities: {} [ROLE_OWNER]
Loaded user details: {}Gulnoza
Token is valid: {}true
Gulnoza
Security context set: SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.marketplace.JWT.UsersInfo.OwnerInfoDetails@3c453603, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_OWNER]]]
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(): {} UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.marketplace.JWT.UsersInfo.OwnerInfoDetails@3c453603, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_OWNER]]

Checking match of request : '/welcome'; against '/welcome/**'
matched
Checking authorization on '/welcome' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedReactiveAuthorizationManager@6a93aa08
Authorization failed: Access Denied
```

I tried to change hasRole to hasAuthority, but it didnt help. I'm stucked!